# Perform logout in Sharepoint 2010 Login Control

Tags: c#, iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, login-control

I am trying to customize the login control

```
public partial class LoginControl : UserControl
```

in sharepoint 2010 application but I am getting this error message after the login control performs loggedin event:

```
System.ArgumentException: Eine Ausnahme vom Typ "System.ArgumentException" wurde ausgelöst.  Parametername: encodedValue    bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimEncodingManager.DecodeClaimFromFormsSuffix(String encodedValue)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderManager.GetProviderUserKey(String encodedIdentityClaimSuffix)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHeaderManager.AddIsapiHeaders(HttpContext context, String encodedUrl, NameValueCollection headers)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PreRequestExecuteAppHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)     bei System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I did a research and found out that the problem is cause because another users session is still open and not logged out.([This issue occurs because an invalid user context is left in the IIS cache.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2988406))

Is there any way for me to ensure the user is signed out before I try to sign in the user?